# Change the tmux status bar background color depending on copy-mode

Tags: colors, tmux

**How do I change the background color of the tmux bar to a different color depending on if the client is in copy-mode (or not)?**

The goal is to make it extremely clear when the tmux client is in copy-mode.

### How to detect copy-mode in a format string

I found `#{?#{!=:#{selection_present},},COPY-MODE,NORMAL-MODE}` works.

### What I tried

#### Set `status-left` or `status-right`

This only changes the style of one part of the bar. Example:

`set -g status-left '#{?#{!=:#{selection_present},},#[bg=yellow],#[bg=green]}#{=10:session_name}@#{=10:host_short}`

This'll show `session@hostname` in the bottom left, and it will change background, but does not change the color of the entire status bar.

#### Set `status-style` with a format string

`set -F -g status-style 'bg=#{?#{!=:#{selection_present},},yellow,green},fg=black`

This appears to evaluate the format strings **only once**. *Note: If I remove the `-F` bg does not change.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a hook, something like:

```
set-hook -g pane-mode-changed 'if -F "#{m/r:(copy|view)-mode,#{pane_mode}}" "set status-style bg=red" "set -u status-style"'
```

If your tmux is too old for m/r you can use something like `#{||:#{==:#{pane_mode},copy-mode},#{==:#{pane_mode},view-mode}}` instead.

Alternatively you could modify status-format[0] but that would be kind of fiddly because status-style is the implicit default.